# ggplot_line from a big dataframe with different columns and variables

Tags: r, graph

I have a big dataframe with a lot of rows (+50k). There are some columns but the importants ones are "Date", "Stock", "Units_Sells". The dataframe is something like:

```
df <- data.frame(Product=sample(LETTERS[1:4],15, replace=TRUE), 
                              Stock=sample(1:15,15,replace=TRUE), 
                              Store=sample(2340:2342,15,replace=TRUE),
                              Vta=sample(1:14,15,replace=TRUE),
                              Date=sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 15))
```

And I would like to create a graph line store by store and Product when x-axis are the Date and y-axis are Units because the values (lines) should be Stock and Vta.
I mean, I would like to do a graph like this for each Store-Product:
[LINK TO THE GRAPH EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oePyq.png)

I mean, one graph for each store&product. I don't know if I'm explaining because english is not my native language.

Thank you,

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's easier to troubleshoot if you show some code.

Comment: Well, sorry but I'm learning R and I don't know how to start.... ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I've gathered is that you want to do a graph for each combination of Product and Store. Then you have two graphs for each combination, one displaying `Vta` and one displaying `Stock`.

To do this, I've slightly changed your example to include more observations:

```
df <- data.frame(Product=sample(LETTERS[1:4],100, replace=TRUE), 
                 Stock=sample(1:15,100,replace=TRUE), 
                 Store=sample(2340:2342,100,replace=TRUE),
                 Vta=sample(1:14,100,replace=TRUE),
                 Date=sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 100))
```

You then have to re-shape the dataframe in order to have two lines on your graph:

```
df <- tidyr::gather(df, key = "type", value = "value", -Store, -Date, -Product)
```

Then you can create your graph like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Stock/Vta graph
ggplot(df, aes(Date, value, col = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Store~Product) +
  ggtitle("Stock/Vta")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Maybe I haven't exaplained myself. I attached a picture to my initial post to show you how I would like the graphs looks. :)

Comment: I just edited my post. It should now do what you want.

Comment: Did the posted solution work? If it did, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey Stan125, sorry but I couldn't answer. I've tried with your example and it works like I would like, BUT with my example it's not working. Maybe there are a lot of data in? I don't know. I'll try your code with an other little sample from my data and I'll answer you. Thank you a lot for your time/help.

Comment: The problem probably lies in the `tidyr::gather()` function. In order to convert your dataframe as above, you have to control for all columns that you don`t want to transform. I indicated this with `-Store, -Date, -Product`, but if you have more columns then you have to control for those as well, putting them also in the `gather` function, with `gather(..., -var1, -var2)` and so on. So if you have more columns than the reproducible example above you must control for those columns as well.